# PHP: Controlled Random to generate 2-3 fixed events per week per user

Tags: php, datetime

I have calendars of different users that I need to fill with 2 - 3 events per week. The events should be generated randomly, however, calling this "random week-events function" should always result in the same events for each week and each user. Note: Each user has a unique userid (1, 2, ...).

Now I need a function where I throw in the userid and the week (or a date within a week) and it returns 2 or 3 events within this week, example for one of the events returned: `2015-11-02 21:00:00` to `2015-11-02 21:30:00`. Format is datetime (in MySql). Each event should be 30 min, 60 min, 90 min or 120 min.

The event times should be between 09:00 and 22:00h.

Any help to solve this is appreciated.

Comment: Downvote and a close flag for `unclear what you're asking` and `too broad`? I think it is very clear what I mean. If not, ask what is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have come up with, maybe it helps someone:

```
function get_pseudoevents($weekid, $userid)
{
    // more probabilitiy for 60 and 90 min
    $durations = array(30, 30, 60, 60, 60, 90, 90, 90, 120);

    // we produce some fixed "random" here
    $helper = $weekid*$userid;
    $weekday_one = $helper%7; // result 0...6
    $weekday_two = ($weekday_one + $userid)%7;
    $hours_one = $helper%10 + 10; // result 10...20
    $hours_two = ($helper + $userid + $weekid)%10 + 10; // result 10...20
    $duration_one = $durations[$helper%9];
    $duration_two = $durations[$hours_two%9];

    $time_one = 0;
    $time_two = 0;

    // get first day of week from recent year
    $recentyear = date('Y');
    $weekid_lz = str_pad($weekid, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT); // leading zero, e.g. 1 becomes 01
    $startdate = strtotime($recentyear.'W'.$weekid_lz); // 2015W34
    $time_one = $startdate + $weekday_one*24*60*60 + $hours_one*60*60;
    $time_one_end = $time_one + $duration_one*60;
    $time_two = $startdate + $weekday_two*24*60*60 + $hours_two*60*60;
    $time_two_end = $time_two + $duration_two*60;

    $times = array();
    // $pseu_start = '2015-10-16 10:00:00'; $pseu_end = '2015-10-16 11:00:00';
    array_push($times, array( 'start' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$time_one), 'end' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$time_one_end)) );
    array_push($times, array( 'start' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$time_two), 'end' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$time_two_end)) );

    // 3 events if even week, otherwise only 2
    if($weekid%2==0)
    {
        $weekday_three = ($weekid + $weekday_one + $userid)%7;
        $hours_three = ($hours_two + $weekid%5)%10 + 10; // result 10...20
        $duration_three = $durations[$hours_three%9];
        $time_three = 0;

        $time_three = $startdate + $weekday_three*24*60*60 + $hours_three*60*60;
        $time_three_end = $time_three + $duration_three*60;

        array_push($times, array( 'start' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$time_three), 'end' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$time_three_end)) );
    }
    return $times;
}
```